# Is it possible to create an EC2 instance from a Launch Configuration via command line interface or API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling

Amazon AWS allows you to create Launch Configurations to be used with auto scaling groups. 
However how can you spin-up up an individual instance instance based on a launch configuration?

Comment: A single instance can be an autoscale group with max and min instances set to 1, no?

Comment: A launch configuration is simply a template that applies to your EC2 instances in an AutoScaling group. Is there any requirement to your question where it wouldn't be acceptable to create an AutoScaling group of instance size 1?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to create an ASG in order to create an instance from a launch config, following is the command. Change min, max and desired capacities as per your needs. [Refer the doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/autoscaling/create-auto-scaling-group.html).

```
aws autoscaling create-auto-scaling-group --auto-scaling-group-name my-auto-scaling-group --launch-configuration-name my-launch-config --min-size 0 --max-size 1 --desired-capacity 1 --vpc-zone-identifier subnet-41767929c
```

once the instance is launched you can detached the instance and delete the ASG.

```
aws autoscaling detach-instances --instance-ids i-2a2d8978 --auto-scaling-group-name my-asg --should-decrement-desired-capacity
```

to delete the ASG

```
aws autoscaling delete-auto-scaling-group --auto-scaling-group-name my-asg
```

However pls check your requirement again and this is NOT a recommended way to do things in AWS. Use a service like Cloud formation instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for using a template to create an instance, you could use [AWS CloudFormation](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/). With CloudFormation, you could create a template and use CloudFormation CLI or API to launch it. Here is [a sample template to launch an instance](https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-templates-us-west-2/EC2InstanceWithSecurityGroupSample.template).

If you want to reuse launch configuration, you can still use [AWS CloudFormation](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/) to create a template with AutoScaling group, like [this](https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-templates-us-west-2/ELBWithLockedDownAutoScaledInstances.template).  Actually the launch configuration could be defined in CloudFormation template.

Answer (score 0):

On the CLI, i believe `aws autoscaling set-desired-capacity` is what you want. Or you can just set the desired capacity on the management console.

see: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/autoscaling/set-desired-capacity.html

Answer (score 0):

As of Dec 2017 this can now be done from the CLI or console. You no longer have to use an Auto Scale Group.

For example:

```
aws ec2 run-instances --launch-template LaunchTemplateId=lt-0abcd290751193123,Version=1
```

See detail at AWS https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-launch-templates.html#launch-instance-from-launch-template

Comment: This is for Launch Templates which is different from Launch Configuration which is what the OP is asking about.

Answer (score -1):

```
aws ec2 run-instances --launch-template LaunchTemplateId=lt-123456789,Version=1
```

where `lt-123456789` is your launch template id